# Why does empty("0") returns true in PHP?

Tags: php

According to PHP documentation, the following expressions return true when calling `empty($var)`

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- **"0" (0 as a string)**
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

I've found how to "solve" the problem by using `empty($var) && $var != 0` but why php developers did it?

I think it is ridiculous, suppose you have this code:

```
if (empty($_POST["X"])) {
    doSomething();
}
```

I think `"0"` is not empty, empty is when there is nothing!

Maybe it's better to use

```
if (isset($x) && x != "") {//for strings
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Because 0 also means false.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, it's a legitimate question since "empty" implies a lack of data, whereas "0" is a legitimate string.  I'm interested to know the reasoning behind this as well.

Comment: Because this is *how* it is defined. It could have been differently, but it is/was not. One might blame perl's false-y value conversions as the basis of the inspiration ..

Comment: @user2864740 Both the original author and myself understand that, the question is **why** `empty` is defined like this, since `"0"` is quite clearly not empty.

Comment: because `"" == 0 == 0.0 == "0" == null == false == array() == $var`.  php is loosely typed.

Comment: at the time when they decided to call this feature(it isn't a function) `empty`, a string `'0'` wasn't empty.

Answer (score 21):

`empty` *roughly mirrors* [PHP's selection of FALSE-y values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - **the empty string, and the string "0"**
> - an array with zero elements
> - ...

As far as *why* PHP works this way, or *why* the empty function followed suit - well, that's Just The Way It Is.

Consider using `strlen($x)` (this is especially well-suited to sources like `$_POST` which are all string values) to determine if there is a non-empty string, including "0".

The final form I use would then be: `isset($x) && strlen($x)`, with any additional processing applied knowing there was *some* post data.

Comment: The use of quotes do majorily affect the data type of the actual value. It's worth a note also

Comment: thanks, but about booleans i have the same question, why "0" is evaluated as false? but it doesn't matter, i'm goint to solve it by using strlen or == "" or whatever... i was wondering why php developers designed php in that way

Comment: @user2961204 Because it is how PHP is - there need not be rational rationale, and the choice is history. Barring finding an original manifesto or design/notes, such decisions are generally lost and do not make good SO questions. Every language establishes values of truth/false-y, some stricter than others: e.g. Python/Ruby adopt much narrower definitions of false-y values. I suspect that PHP was heavily influenced by Perl (a dominate competitor at the time), which has [similarly "quirky" values](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=what%20is%20true%20and%20false%20in%20Perl%3F).