# When would empty() return false and $var == '' return true?

Tags: php

Got an interesting issue. In some legacy code we have following statements.

```
if (empty($result['email_address']) && empty($result['mobile_number'])) {
    $token = '';
} else {
    $tokenFinder = new TokenFinder();
    $tokenFinder->setEmailAddress($result['email_address']);
    $tokenFinder->setMobileNumber($result['mobile_number']);
    $token = $tokenFinder->generate();
}
```

The relevant bits of the token finder look like the following:

```
class TokenFinder{

    public function setEmailAddress($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function setMobileNumber($mobile) {
        $this->mobile = $mobile;
    }

    public function generate(){
        if ($this->email == '' && $this->mobile == ''){
            Throw new Exception('TokenFinder: You cannot fetch a token with no email or mobile number');
        }
```

Yesterday, for the first time ever, the exception in the `generate()` method was triggered. I have run all of the recipients in the failed message through this block of code and the exception doesn't trigger. The data has not changed since the Exception was thrown. It is a strange one.

Does anyone know any values which will lead `empty($var)` to evaluate to false and `$var == ''` to evalute to true.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100890/in-php-why-empty0-returns-true

Comment: Questions like this are great examples why it's always better to use `===` rather than `==` in languages like PHP and JavaScript to ensure you're checking strict equality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in php, why empty("0") returns true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100890/in-php-why-empty0-returns-true)

Comment: i tried this. $a=array();  var_dump(empty($a));  o/p is bool(true). and $a=='' is false. so may be your input needs to be trimmed and filtered before checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty()` returns `true` in case of:

- empty string
- 0 integer
- 0.0 float
- 0 as string
- null
- false
- empty array
- empty variable

(see http://php.net/empty)

The error must lie in php's tricky type juggling. It could be, that `$result['email_address']` or `$result['mobile_numer']` contain an object which `__toString` implementation return an empty string. `emtpy` will see an object and `== ''` sees an empty string.

There could be dozens of other cases though. So your best possibility is to get rid of the logic duplication (the if statements) and implement maybe a static method in `TokenFinder` like `isDataValid` and use it to check the array outside of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree the code needs reworking in this area. It is on our todo list. Thanks for the suggestion as well with the object idea. I don't think that is the actual problem but it certainly helps come up with other similar scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

PHP manual:

> empty() Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero
>   value. Otherwise returns TRUE.