# PHP how to check for an empty field?

Tags: php

As per [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) empty function check for this type of cases,

```
$var = '';
$var = 0;
$var = 0.0;
$var = FALSE;
$var = NULL;
```

But I came across this if `$var = 0.00` or `.0` or `' '`(space) it is not empty, how can I properly check if a field is empty?

Comment: `0.00` and `.0` should still evaluate as empty unless they are quoted (thus now strings and not floats), but a space is not an empty string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132649/when-would-empty-return-false-and-var-return-true, Please go through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your definition of "empty" isn't the same as PHP's then you'll need to implement a function which makes additional checks for the extra values you consider to consider to represent "empty", as well as the ones which `empty()` already does. i.e. the way to check if it's empty as per your definition, is to check for each of the values you want to check for. Simple as that :-)

Note: `0.00` and `.0` already cause `empty()` to return `true` (demo: https://3v4l.org/v1HNb) so we can ignore those. If you're thinking of the string represenation of those though (i.e. `"0.00"` and `".0"`) then your new function could take those into account.

For example:

```
function extraEmpty($var)
{
  return (empty($var) || $var === "0.00" || $var === ".0" || $var === " ");
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Ri8c3

N.B. I would argue that since `" "` isn't an empty string (i.e. it contains a space which is a perfectly valid character), then it shouldn't be classed as representing "empty", but that's up to you. For consideration: what about a string containing nothing except 2 space characters? or 3? Or 20? or 2000? What do you do with those? You risk opening a can of worms, IMHO.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to test if a string is numeric, and then turn it into a number, before giving it to `empty()`? Better turn it back into a string, and compare it to the original, because some people use strings like `"0.00 Hello"`, which should definitely stay a string. OK, nothing is perfect, but just testing for some cases, and, for instance, not `"0.000"`, or `"0."`, doesn't seem right either.

Comment: I checked again and yes "0.00" or ".0" is a string on my field that's why it's not empty. I am planning to make a function for custom empty, but now you gave me another worry about x no of white spaces.....

Comment: @RaoDYC You can use [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to get rid of spaces.

Comment: @RaoDYC one option is to simply trim the whitespace - demo: https://3v4l.org/FPL27 . That's assuming though that a string containing characters+whitespace at the beginning/end wouldn't need to stay as-is. Although if you just trim within the extraEmpty function and don't persist that change, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I can agree with you...maybe talk to the person who wrote the specification, not me. I think they're perhaps starting to realise they haven't thought this through to its logical conclusion :-)

Comment: @ADyson please check my answer below and let me know if this makes sense

Comment: @RaoDYC It doesn't really, no, because your call to empty() is testing the emptiness of the output of `is_numeric` (i.e. true/false) rather than testing the actual value itself. I don't know if you used a wide range of test cases, but I'd hope that would become apparent with sufficient testing.

Answer (score -1):

//This might help you using empty() function to check your variable.

$var = "";
//empty($var)=true

$var = null;
//empty($var)=true

var $var;
//empty($var)=true

$var = "undefined";
//empty($var)=true

$var = array();
//empty($var)=true

$var = false;
//empty($var)=true

$var = true;
//empty($var)=false

$var = 1;
//empty($var)=false

$var = 42;
//empty($var)=false

$var = 0;
//empty($var)=true

$var = -1;
//empty($var)=false

$var = "1";
//empty($var)=false

$var = "0";
//empty($var)=true

$var = "-1";
//empty($var)=false

$var = "php";
//empty($var)=false

$var = "true";
//empty($var)=false

$var = "false";
//empty($var)=false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).